# Customize the “back to parent” ActionBar icon image not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to customize the android Up navigation with my own image ([image: up navigation image]).

style.xml

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_up_nav</item>
    </style>
```

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I already tried adding this line in style "`<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_up_nav</item></style>`" to customize the appearance but the default up navigation image is not changing.

Currently I am having the default up navigation arrow image and i want to change the default with this image  [image]. Application is using the theme "`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use in your Activity OnCreate method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.custom_up_nav);
```

Comment: @user2681579 glad it helped. Please accept it as an answer, thanks.